# Getting HTML Source with Excel-VBA - Pop Up Window

Tags: html, vba

The post below has a method to extract the HTML of a url using the following code.

[Getting HTML Source with Excel-VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520949/getting-html-source-with-excel-vba)

```
    Public Function getHTTP(ByVal url As String) As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", url, False: .Send
        getHTTP = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
End Function
```

The code works great, but my issue is that the website that I have (an internal website) has a pop-up window the first time I log into it. So accessing through this method gets me the HTML of the pop-up. How can I get beyond this window?

[image]

When operating the website manually, the first time I access the web page, the pop-up appears for a few seconds then it disappears and I have click on a button to login.

---

Update:
Taking a deeper dive, the html returned is the login window for the site. Normally on this intranet based site, my first access in the day, I click a 'continue' button (no username/password) and it auto logs me in. And any time I access the site moving forward I can go directly to parts of the site without re-logging in. The link that I am using as my url is a direct link to a certain page on the site. Curious on how to get XMLHTTP logged into the site...

[image]

Here is the login - it is not a standard username and password. It is a username, password, department and city. Also a radio button to toggle between 2 settings. Then I would click on login.

Comment: Is there anything unique in the head of the popup window? Perhaps something like this could be evaluated in your function? `If SomeUniqueAttribute = True Then DoTheFunction Else WaitForSomeTimer` maybe?

Comment: May be you can use the [Wait method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa213656(v=office.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) or a while loop to wait until the expected html source available?

Comment: If you are looking for solutions irrespective of tools, then I would highly recommend Selenium to achieve the same.

Comment: Can you do an initial login xhr ?

Comment: Dhamo: I am trying to get away from using a browser to get the results. QHarr: Can you elaborate how to "do initial login xhr".

Answer (score 0):

I would firstly try this small modification, in order to exactly obtain the `responseBody` of the intermediary page (only one time):

```
Public Function getHTTP(ByVal url As String) As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", url, False: .send
        Debug.print StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode):getHTTP = ""
    End With
End Function
```

And then I would copy the response from `Immediate Window` and use it next adapted code:

```
Public Function getHTTP(ByVal url As String) As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", url, False: .send

        Do While StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode) = "the copied text from Immediate Window"
            DoEvents
        Loop
        getHTTP = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
End Function
```

Or, if the response is too long, use `Left("the text in discussion", 10) = "Whatever x"`

Edited: Try transforming of your initial function in the next way, to include authentication:

```
Public Function getHTTP(ByVal url As String) As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", url, False: .Send
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & Base64Encode(Your_User & ":" & password)
        getHTTP = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. So it appears that it is stuck on the login. I have reconstructed the HTML and there is a hyperlink at the "here". Any way to click on it? {In case the automatic authentication is not working for your account you may login manually <a href="LoginWithCredentials.jsp">here</a>}

Comment: @M. Marzouk: If no solution found, try my last update (after Edited). It includes a way of authentification...

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet. I have updated the main question to add how the login looks like. There is more than a username and password input. Any thoughts on how to address that?